# How do I detect an object size in Sci-Kit Learn / Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network, image-segmentation

I'm building an app that needs to recognize the size of an object in an image. I need to be able to read in a picture of a cucumber and then tell how many pixels long the cucumber is. I've built an image classifier in the past but am not sure how to retrieve the classified image and find the dimensions.

I have basic understanding of machine learning and sci-kit learn. Any suggestions or guides would be extremely helpful and appreciated!

EDIT: This may sound dumb, but can I throw anything into a neural network to get automatic results? For instance, could I train a NN on images of cucumbers with targets of their lengths and expect the neural network to learn that I'm wanting to retrieve pixel lengths from the images?

Comment: You're referring to *image segmentation*. Image segmentation and image classification are examples of machine learning "tasks".

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I have updated my question a bit

Comment: >For instance, could I train a NN on images of cucumbers with targets of their lengths and expect the neural network to learn that I'm wanting to retrieve pixel lengths from the images?
yes you can. this is called regression. Best way to do this is to first build a classification DNN. Afterwards strip the fully connected layer and replace it with a layer for regression where target is the number of pixel. However, you will need a shitload of training data

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! So when building the classification DNN do I just train on images of cucumbers and other random items and 0 or 1 as to whether or not it is actually a cucumber? I don't plan on using any pics other than cucumbers when I actually use the app so I'm not sure if I totally need an object classifier.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your use case is, it may be much better to use [OpenCV. It has bindings for python, C, C++ and java.](http://opencv.org/). If your cucumbers are on always the same background this is 100% the route I would take, because OpenCV has methods exactly for doing this type of thing.

If for some reason you must use TF in production, then you should still use OpenCV to prepare the data to train the neural net on. Prepare a bunch of example images of cucumbers, use OpenCV to snip out the cucumber and place it into about 500,000 sample images (scaled and rotated random amounts, and perhaps with a bit of shear or blur or both) and use that as your dataset to feed into TF. 
You should be able to feed in the True/False value(cucumber or not), along with a size. As far as I know it should learn them both.

Make sure you include lots images of an empty scene, and then images of the  same scene with your target object in it. Ideally you would want to use the same environment that your application will run in.

Sorry for posting an answer instead of a comment. Not enough reputation yet.

P.S. It is **much** easier to detect objects if you get to do it using the color rather than just shape.

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I will look into OpenCV. Unfortunately, the background will be different each time and I will have to recognize the shape and not just the color.

Comment: Haar cascades in OpenCV may be sufficient. There are tutorials located here https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-images-python-opencv-tutorial/